# Print the first and last values of 2 consecutive data entries of a dataset in order to plot the differences - in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of monthly survey answers from individuals starting in Month2 and ending in M13.  I want to plot the difference from M2 to M3, M3 to M4, M4 to M5, etc.  Ideally, I will be able to create new columns to easily use to plot the data.

An example of the dataset is this

```
ID  M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12 M13
1   5   15  2   20  .   .   .   4   2   7   8   .
2   2   8   7   6   5   4   7   4   7   9   9   8
3   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   7   7
4   6   7   8   6   .   .   .   .   .   7   6   5
```

So the ideal output for ID 1 would be

```
First   Last
5   15
15  2
2   20
4   2
2   7
7   8
```

I will eventually want to capture the first and last value for anyone with 3 consecutive months all the way up the 11 consecutive months.

Any thoughts on where I would start with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
ID M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12 M13
1   5   15  2   20  .   .   .   4   2   7   8   .
2   2   8   7   6   5   4   7   4   7   9   9   8
3   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   7   7
4   6   7   8   6   .   .   .   .   .   7   6   5
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(M,First,-ID) %>%                 # reshape data
  group_by(ID) %>%                        # for each ID
  mutate(Last = lead(First)) %>%          # get the next values in a new column
  ungroup() %>%                           # forget the grouping
  filter(First != "." & Last != ".") %>%  # exclude rows with . as value
  arrange(ID) %>%                         # order ID (needed for visualisation purposes only)
  select(-M)                              # remove unnecessary column


# # A tibble: 23 x 3
#      ID First Last 
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 5     15   
# 2     1 15    2    
# 3     1 2     20   
# 4     1 4     2    
# 5     1 2     7    
# 6     1 7     8    
# 7     2 2     8    
# 8     2 8     7    
# 9     2 7     6    
# 10    2 6     5    
# # ... with 13 more rows
```

Columns `First` and `Last` are `character` because you had `.` as a value. You can update them to be `numeric` if you want.

Assuming that this was the case of 2 consecutive months, you can use the above code as a function that takes as input the number of consecutive months you want to consider (as the dataset `df` is always the same):

```
# function that gets as input the number of consecutive months you want to consider
f = function(x) {

df %>%
  gather(M,First,-ID) %>%                 # reshape data
  group_by(ID) %>%                        # for each ID
  mutate(Last = lead(First, x-1)) %>%     # get the next values in a new column
  ungroup() %>%                           # forget the grouping
  filter(First != "." & Last != ".") %>%  # exclude rows with . as value
  arrange(ID) %>%                         # order ID (needed for visualisation purposes only)
  select(-M)                              # remove unnecessary column
}
```

You can run `f(2)`, `f(3)`, ... `f(11)` and check results, or you can create a big dataset with all combinations, like this:

```
# create a series of consecutive months (2 to 11) and apply the function to each value
data.frame(consec_months = 2:11) %>%
  mutate(d = map(consec_months, ~f(.))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  tbl_df()       # only for visualisation purposes

# # A tibble: 114 x 4
#   consec_months    ID First Last 
#           <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1             2     1 5     15   
# 2             2     1 15    2    
# 3             2     1 2     20   
# 4             2     1 4     2    
# 5             2     1 2     7    
# 6             2     1 7     8    
# 7             2     2 2     8    
# 8             2     2 8     7    
# 9             2     2 7     6    
# 10            2     2 6     5    
# # ... with 104 more rows
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thank you!   Will 3 consecutive months and so on be difficult?  Also just looking for the First and Last values

Comment: I didn't get how the 3 consecutive months, etc. will look like. Is the above solution considered as 2 consecutive months?

Comment: Yes, I think that is two consecutive months.  
ID 1 for 3 would look like: 

'First last
5 2
15 20
4 7
2 8'

Comment: 5 2 | 15 20 | 4 7 | 2 8 |
Sorry not sure how to show it appropriately

Comment: Yes, I think I got it! Check my updated answer. Hope it's clear how you can use the function, or the big table with all combinations.

Comment: Amazing!  All looks good.  I made my scatterplots and am ready to roll.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Revisiting this for another variable.  How would I also capture everything in between the first and last?

So For ID 1 the 3 consecutive answer would be the following:
5,15,2 | 15,2,20 | 4,2,7 | 2,7,8